# Optimization Experiment internal error (no model BUILD problems) - anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I built my model and got Zero problems.
The Simulation Experiment is running without any errors (I'm using test/random values for the parameters)

However, when I run the Optimization Experiment, I'm getting the following 500 errors:

[image]

[image]

- I have 246 `int` parameters in the optimization experiments ( I know too much but did not return any problem while building the model, I used the same number before in a different problem, and it worked totally fine)
- I have defined 1756 constraints ( I know too much, but still under the limit of 65535 bytes and did not return any problem while building the model )

I have used `root` to define my constraints as below (**maybe this is causing errors?** but did not return any problem while building the model):

[image]

Comment: Try isolating further. Reduce constraints and params. When does it kick in?

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin. I will try and get back to you here.   
The errors kick in directly after I click the run button.  
What about the constraints do you think root. should be removed? I tried before in another model to define the constraints without the root. and it worked fine (but it was only 3 constraints)

Comment: root refers to `Main` typically. So if you have objects called `x1` on Main, do not remove them. But I have never seen it done, typically you keep them in the experiment

Comment: Thank you very much, Benjamin. Your methodology in how to find the reason for errors helped a lot. Please see my answer. I don't understand why AnyLogic doesn't return a problem while building the model if it does not allow parameters with type 'int' to have a step size bigger than 1. This would have saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this 500 Error (internal error) is the type of the parameter and the step size defined in the optimization experiment panel (Parameters).
What I have found is as follows:
if you use the `int` type for a parameter, its step size must be 1
if you use the `discrete` type for a parameter, its step size can be any integer (for example 4)

Even one parameter is not allowed to break this role, otherwise AnyLogic will return the same error message : 500 Error

Comment: thx for sharing, weird indeed